# Is it possible to trigger a click event from another form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

I need to run the code of a button that is on another form. is it possible to do it from a different form? if you say that it is possible by declaring it public then:

1. how do i declare a control public?
2. how do i pass the correct events into `button_click`? it takes two parameters  - how do i pass them,?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to make a control in a `Form` `public`, but not recommended, you can do the following:

1) Declare a new event in the first form (form1) ButtonFirstFormClicked

```
public event EventHandler ButtonFirstFormClicked;
```

and trigger this event in the Button.Click event handler

```
void button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // if you're working with c# 6.0 or greater
    ButtonFirstFormClicked?.Invoke(sender, e);

    // if you're not then comment the above method and uncomment the below
    //if (ButtonFirstFormClicked!= null)
    //     ButtonFirstFormClicked(sender, e);
}
```

2) In the second form (form2) subscribe the event

```
form1.ButtonFirstFormClicked += (s, e)
{
 // put your code here...
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: So you are putting the code outside Form1? I am sorry but your explanation is hard to understand. Which form calls which?

Comment: Sorry for the downvote but your solution is not clear

Answer (score 17):

Why not create a public method in a shared class that both `click` events execute.

Comment: +1 for good design advice.  There should be nothing but a call to another event within an event handler anyway (although validation of inputs wouldn't hurt, but even that could be in the other method called by the event handler.)

Comment: i respect you very much because unlike other high rollers like yourself, they mark their own answers up so that they do not have negatives

Answer (score 3):

You can use internal as your modifier, so you can easily access the click event.

for example you have a click event in form1.
instead of making it private, public or protected. put it as internal this way 
you can easily access the method in other classes. But the [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah1b9xxb%28VS.80%29.aspx) modifier is only accessible within the 
current package.

**Form1**

```
internal passobj;
internal passeargs;

internal void button1_Click(object obj, EventArgs e)
{
 this.passobj = obj;
 this.passeargs = e;

 MessageBox.Show("Clicked!")
}
```

**Form2**

```
private void button1_Click(object obj, EventArgs e)
{

   Form1 f1 = new Form1();
   f1.button1_Click(f1.passobj, f1.passeargs);
}
```

Comment: can u please give me an example

Comment: see my edit above, I have done this several times and i think its safe to use internal modifier. i think you can also do that using public modifier.

Answer (score 1):

In the form where the code is (firstForm) you will need to make the procedure public and avaliable to the secondary form where the secondary button is (btnMyButton).  Once you have accomplished this you can hook up the click event hander of the secondary button to the code in the 1st form as follows.

Secondarily as stated above by **Dustin** you could opt to move this code into a separate class and then simply reference the method handler with as many events as you need.

Either way will work but I agree that if you want to follow good design you should have a separation of concerns as it relates to business logic (code) and presentation layer (ie forms with buttons)

//button in 2nd form

```
btnMyButton.Click += new EventHandler(firstForm.MethodThatHasCodeToRun);
```

Hope this helps,

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can make the control public by changing the "Modifiers" pseudo-property in the form designer.
2. Once the button is public, you can run its `Click` event by calling the `PerformClick` method, e.g. `form1.button1.PerformClick()`. You don't have to call the event handler directly.

However, it might be a better idea to create a public method as Dustin Laine suggests.