# Call button from another Form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, events, button

I'm trying to call a button which is in a form via a class1. So in my Form I have:

```
 public LoadSettings loadSet;  //refering to a class2
```

and a button event:

```
 public void loadSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        loadSettingsClicked = true;
        var loadSet = new LoadSettings(this);
        loadSet.load_settings(sender);

    }
```

So it's a button which calls a method in a class2 and executes something. Now I'm in a class1 and I want to call this button from there. In this class1 I have:

```
         public Form1 form1 = null;

    public Class1(Form1 frm1)
    {
        form1 = frm1;
    }
```

and now I want to call the button from there:

```
    form1.loadSettings_Click(this);
```

but he doesn't want. He recognizes the form etc but how do I call the button?

Comment: Just call the same method from `Class1` that you call from `Class2`. Trying to "call a button" from one form to another is a recipe for headaches.

Comment: Please check below link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110755/c-sharp-is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-click-event-from-another-form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `form1.loadSettings_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);`