# How to let MainWindow know that in Folder/Page2.xaml a Button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my MainWindow.xaml i have a Frame. The content of this Frame will change when i click a Button. So if I click a button to show private customers, the Frame Content shows the site of the private customers:

```
private void privatecustomer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Content = new Privatecustomer.privatecustomer_show();
    }
```

After clicking this Button the Frame will change the Content.
The new Content shows Privatecustomer.privatecustomer_show.xaml now.
In this xaml i have another Button. If i click this Button, the Content of the Frame in MainWindow should change to "Privatecustomer.privatecustomer_add.xaml".

But How I can tell from privatecustomer_show.xaml to MainWindow.xaml, that the Button addPrivatecustomer in privatecustomer_show is clicked and that the Main.Content have to change to

```
Main.Content = new Privatecustomer.privatecustomer_add();
```

?
I hope I can get some help here

Comment: maybe this answer can help you : [Is it possible to trigger a click event from another form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110755/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-click-event-from-another-form)

Comment: In privatecustomers_show.xaml:
`public event EventHandler ButtonFirstFormClicked;

        public void addPrivatkunde(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ButtonFirstFormClicked != null)
                ButtonFirstFormClicked(sender, e);
        }`
And in MainWindow.xaml:
`Privatecustomer.privatecustomer_show.ButtonFirstFormClicked += (s, e)
            {
                Main.Content = new Privatecustomer.privatecustomer_add();
            }`
But this don't work cuz MainWindow dont know `Privatecustomer.privatecustomer_show.ButtonFirstFormClicked += (s, e)`

Comment: Each time you click, do you handle the same page or do you create a new one ?

Comment: How u mean? I have my MainWindow.xaml. There is a Frame which shows Pages i want to see. If i click the Button "Private Customers" on MainWindow. The Frame shows me the content from privatecustomers_show.xaml. This works. But I want that the Frame.Content in MainWindow change to "Main.Content = new privatecustomer_add" when i click a button in privatecustomers_show.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an event in privatecustomer_show.xaml that the MainWindow.xaml can subscribe to.

Like this

```
  public event EventHandler AddPrivateCustomer;

  protected virtual void OnAddPrivateCustomerEventArgs e) 
  {
     if (AddPrivateCustomer!= null)
        AddPrivateCustomer(this, e);
  }
```

Update: Please note the updated code, I made a copy'n'paste mistake in my first version.

Change your:
    private void privatecustomer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

To:

```
private void privatecustomer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var privateCustomerContent=new Privatecustomer.privatecustomer_show();
  privateCustomerContent.AddPrivateCustomer+=onClick_addPrivateCustomer;
  Main.Content = privateCustomerContent;
}

private onClick_addPrivateCustomer(object o,EventArgs e)
{
  // Change Main.Content
}
```

The idea is that your privatecustomer_show control sends events for when it want to change something outside of what it has access to.
You MainWindow which has full control of all its child windows will then subscribe to each event.

Comment: I dont understand this. 
If i put ur Code in privatecustomer_show.xaml.cs, visual studio gives me namepsace error cuz he dont know  "AddPrivateCustomerEventHandler"

Comment: See my updated code, I made a coding mistake in the first version.

Comment: You can probably make it more simple by changing the design of your app.
Instead of having the add button inside the showcustomer control, show it in the MainWindow instead.

    -----------------------
    MainWindow
      ------- ShowCustomer -------
      |        Customer List           |
      ------------------------------------
    [Add Customer] [Delete Customer]

Does this make sense?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ZViIqIZ.png I hope u can understand this picture. This is what I want. Your `protected virtual void OnAddPrivateCustomerEventArgs e) 
  {
     if (AddPrivateCustomer!= null)
        AddPrivateCustomer(this, e);
  }` doesnt work :/

Comment: i tryed to change `protected virtual void OnAddPrivateCustomerEventArgs e)` to `protected virtual void OnAddPrivateCustomer(EventArgs e)`
But still don't work

Comment: @xKushGene did you figure it out? My notification was not enabled so I didn't see your latest comments.

What error are you getting now?

Answer (score 0):

Set `Page2.Tag` property to the instance of your `MainWindow` (use Binding in Xaml, or simply set it in code). After the specified Button in Page2 is clickd, simply use the Tag property (which is now your MainWindow).

Another option is to use

```
App.Current.MainWindow
```

When the Button is clicked. (A warning. I don't know the structure your project and this might not be the instance you are looking for).

Comment: I dont think so. I dont have multiple windows. I have 1 Window (MainWindow.xaml) and in this MainWindow is a Frame which includes Pages whith a click on a Button